# Open weather map gives me Bad request

Tags: java, api, android-studio, openweathermap

I am trying to call open weather map api from android studio but it sometimes gives me `401 Unauthorized` or `400 Bad request` I have tried to change api key but it does not work tho I also tried to change the weather url but it gives me not found I can't find the error but it seems that there is something wrong on the website.

> Blockquote

```
 // Constants:
final int REQUEST_CODE = 123;
final String WEATHER_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
// App ID to use OpenWeather data
final String APP_ID = "776a27857ef2d1df5e018d2bdde968d4";
// Time between location updates (5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds)
final long MIN_TIME = 5000;
// Distance between location updates (1000m or 1km)
final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

private static final String TAG = "WeatherController";
```

> Blockquote

```
private void getWeatherForCurrentUser() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged() callback recieved");

            String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + longitude);
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + latitude);

            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("lat" , latitude);
            params.put("long" , longitude);
            params.put("appid" , APP_ID);
            letsDoSomeNetworking(params);

        }
```

> Blockquote

```
private void letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params){

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(WEATHER_URL , params , new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

        @Override

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode , Header[] headers , JSONObject response){

            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode , Header[] headers , Throwable e , JSONObject response){
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage().toString() );
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + statusCode);

            Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this, "Request Failed" + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key for longitude is `lon` not `long`. Check the api specs [here](https://openweathermap.org/current).

Use this:

```
params.put("lon" , longitude);
```